# Can't set PHP block visibility programatically

Tags: blocks

Heres my code:

```
$blocks['membership_package_information'] = array( 
    'info' => "Membership Package Information",
    'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_PHP,
    'pages' => membership_block_visibility(),
  );

function membership_block_visibility() {
  if(arg(0) == 'checkout' && arg(2) == null) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to limit the block to only show on the first page of the drupal commerce checkout page (checkout/[order-id]) and not the second (checkout/[order-id]/review) but its not working. When I put this code in the PHP visibility section of the block UI page, it works. I'd rather it be in my module, why wont it work? It seems that the UI settings are being picked up and not whats in my block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7 you have to put the actual PHP code "in" the `pages` array key...

> For BLOCK_VISIBILITY_PHP, the PHP code's return value should be TRUE if
>   the block is to be made visible or FALSE if the block should not be
>   visible.

...not set it to the return of a function, eg, something along these lines:

```
$blocks['membership_package_information'] = array( 
    'info' => "Membership Package Information",
    'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_PHP,
    'pages' => '<?php return membership_block_visibility(); ?>' // ADDITION: you need the <?php ?> brackets :)
);

// make sure this function is in a module file that is always loaded...

function membership_block_visibility() {
  if(arg(0) == 'checkout' && arg(2) == null) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Do also note the caveat off the api page:

> Most modules do not provide an initial value for 'visibility' or
>   'pages', and any value provided can be modified by a user on the block
>   configuration screen.

Comment: I tried this, and removed all of my php code from the UI php section, but it didn't work - now the blocks display on all pages aka- its not picking up my code!

Comment: I even tried using this line 'pages' => 'return false;', and the blocks still show.

Comment: the block module checks to make sure that you have the `php` module installed so it can `php_eval()` the contents of `'pages'`.  I'd IMAGINE you couldn't have the PHP option in the UI without it, but just make sure it is installed and turned on, etc.

Comment: going to the block ui should clear all the caches necessary but that might be an issue, so try the every present clear your caches suggestion. also sometimes things are only run when a module is first installed, so  you may have to disable, uninstall, and re-enable your module for everything to get re-synced.

Comment: php filter is installed, and I did clear the caches. Why would I need to reinstall the module? when I created the module in the first place, it didn't yet have the blocks installed.

Comment: the block module relies upon `hook_modules_uninstalled()` to clean up its tables when another module is uninstalled so your uninstall/re enable would put everything back to square one for certain.

Comment: would I have to actually uninstall it or just disable it? I don't know if I need the data stored in the tables and don't feel comfortable deleting it. Is there a way to inspect the database tables to find the issue and deal with it from there?

Comment: to see if this is the case, just create a exact duplicate block in your module but with a new delta.  if that works then you know the various caches and tables aren't getting cleared.

Comment: ^^ sure, just look at the `blocks` table and see what it has in there for this block.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11569/discussion-between-user1015214-and-jimajamma)